# How to merge two image together in single format

Tags: javascript

Is there anyone who can help me for merging two image together in java-script (other languages can also be accepted)
For eg:
suppose i have one image that shape may be anything like square rectangle etc, and that i have already uploaded in any format, but later on when i am supposed to upload another images, that should fit in the same previous image and in within the same boundary which is there and intact in same format, and that two together should make one image(My output should be in single image).

Please response will be highly accepted.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are trying to do. Maybe you could illustrate with some images? Like the two pictures you want to "merge" and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Jquery jCrop](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/).

You will need to do the real crop on server side though.